# Import a private repository from linux

Tags: npm, npm-install

The code below works fine with Windows with the command `mpm i`.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "my-pack": "git+https://myprivategit.com/my/repo#v0.1.0"
  },
```

A credential form standard of windows is open, and the login and password is passed.

But on Linux an authetication error is returned.

```
npm install
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://myprivategit.com/my/repo
npm ERR!
npm ERR! remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myprivategit.com/my/repo.git/'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add your credentials, can you try the following:

1. *Generate an access token* for the repository you wish to `npm install` from. For example, go [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens) to create an access token.
2. Prefix your GIT Repo within your `package.json` to use the access token generated from step 1:

   `"dependencies": {
           "my-pack": "git+https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/myprivategit.com/my/repo#v0.1.0"
         },`

**or**:

Create a `.netrc` *within your home directory* and give it the necessary credentials to login:

```
touch ~/.netrc
```

**.netrc:**

```
machine github.com login <token>
```

then just leave the url to your private repo as is within your `.package.json`

Comment: The `.netrc` solved the problem. But your answer `machine github.com login <token>` is not complete. Better explanation here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/45055

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to do the npm install together with my ssh key stored in .ssh.

`npm install git+ssh://git@your_git_server.com:your_username/your_private_repo_name.git`

I followed this [tutorial](https://tolotra.com/2018/11/10/how-to-use-private-git-repo-as-npm-package/).